# Xcode runtime error for iOS iPhone 8 - [AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:2751

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting a runtime error from Xcode in the debug window when I run my app on an actual iPhone 8 device:

> [AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:2751

I have no idea what code that is coming from. I am using the Notification Content Extension.

What is causing this error message?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I got the same message

Comment: @Tometoyou I don’t remember at all.

Comment: @Tometoyou I just got this error again. I don't remember what happened before the error just went away the last time I had this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been logged as a bug (FB7513956) by MADISON SOLARANA with potential fix coming in iOS 13.3.1 beta ([source info](https://msolarana.netlify.app/2020/01/20/bugs-galore/)).

Comment: it's still happening on iOS 16.6 and Xcode 14.3.1 so...

Answer (score 6):

I assume you have this solved by now, but for anyone else visiting, the error is informing you that the api used for AX Lookup is being denied access. If you are using Google Cloud Platform, this may be the case when you have a restricted API key. If this is the case for you,

Go to [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com), view your project, then go to APIs & Services -> Credentials -> click on the API key your iOS app is using, and under API Restrictions add the APIs necessary for your project. If you are using Google Firestore for storage, you should enable the Identity Toolkit API and Cloud Firestore API, in addition to any APIs you might use starting with "Firebase"

Hopefully this helped, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I did not explicitly ask for permission to use the camera in a UIImagePickerController.  It went away when I first did this:

```
   (need   #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>)

    NSString *mediaType = AVMediaTypeVideo;
    [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:mediaType completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             // code to handle granted==NO;

        });
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem when using Firebase. For example if you live in a country (like Cuba, for example) where Firebase is blocked, you may see this error in Xcode console:

```
2022-02-22 10:29:49.790462-0500 PGA[30813:1755604] [AXRuntimeCommon] Unknown client: PGA
2022-02-22 10:29:49.800516-0500 PGA[30813:1755604] [AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:30555 (
    0   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ada00228 66C237CA-4CE1-3DA3-B202-564711E51E84 + 303656
    1   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ad9b9c00 _AXGetPortFromCache + 696
    2   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ad9bb2b4 AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 484
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001de99cab0 A394B4DE-8488-3B7E-B17C-BD9DC2951B2D + 887472
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104548718 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104549f94 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104551150 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 684
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104551dd4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 432
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010455d4e8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 852
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de68de84 _pthread_wqthread + 284
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001de68d9f0 start_wqthread + 8
)
```

But if you install a VPN, then the error disappear. Is just like @Rj_ say !